# Robotframework and SSHLibrary issue with a network router

Tags: robotframework

I am now trying to use SSHLibrary to ssh into a virtual router running on my PC and execute a simple ping test on the router and then present the result of the test case. 
I can login to the router and also execute the command outside of the robotframework, but when I try to do this using robotframework I get a fail with an error message and not sure how i solve for this error message:

Here is my robotframework test script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SSHLibrary
Suite Setup Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown  Close All Connections

*** Variable ***
${HOST}     172.31.1.250
${USERNAME} admin
${PASSWORD} admin

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
    Open Connection     ${HOST}
    Login           ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}

*** Test Cases ***
Ping test
    ${output} = Execute Command     ping 1.1.1.1
    Should Contain  ${result.stdout}    64 bytes from 1.1.1.1
```

Here is the output I get when I execute the above test case:

```
==============================================================================
Sros                                                                          
==============================================================================
Ping test                                                             | FAIL |
ChannelException: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sros                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

What is this error message and how do I solve this:

```
**ChannelException: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')**
```

Does it matter what type of the router that I am login into is?

Thanks for your help.

Based on the feedback I have changed from Execute Command to Write.
So my script looks like this now:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SSHLibrary
Suite Setup Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown  Close All Connections

*** Variable ***
${HOST}     172.31.1.250
${USERNAME} admin
${PASSWORD} admin

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
    Open Connection     ${HOST}
    Login           ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}

*** Test Cases ***
Ping test
    ${result} = Write       ping 1.1.1.1 count 1
    Should Contain  ${result.stdout}    64 bytes from 1.1.1.1
```

But now I get following error message:

```
==============================================================================
Sros                                                                          
==============================================================================
Ping test                                                             | FAIL |
Resolving variable '${result.stdout}' failed: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stdout'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sros                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Also not I have checked using Wireshark that robot script does actually ssh into the router and establish a ssh session. I think the connectivity part of  working fine.

Comment: I think it's somehow related to fact that keyword `Execute Command` starts new shell. Try to use keyword `Write`.

Comment: Hi that helped get rid of the above error. But getting different error now. See my edited post for  the new error.

Comment: Hi, this is because `Write` does not return anything. You need to read output yourself. There are few keyword to do so http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Read

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
Write  ping 1.1.1.1
${output}=  Read  delay=0.5s
```

to get the output in a var. It will now have the same behavior you have while doing it manually !

I hope it will help you ;)